# Unable to upload strings with httpClient to my SSL server

Tags: php, android, ssl, androidhttpclient

I am trying to upload some text to my server using a php web service, with my server having an ssl certificate. When I try another server which doesn't have ssl, it works properly.

Can anyone help me in resolving this problem? I have spent all day searching in this forum.

Please don't tell me that it's repeated question (help that beginner programmer)

This is my code :

```
 protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("base64", ba1));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ImageName", System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arrondi",arrondi));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("controleur",controleur));

        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String st = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.v("log_tag", "In the try Loop" + st);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        return "Success";

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to show the error you are getting, otherwise no-one will know where to start helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to bypass SSL certificate and try again i think it should work..
[How to bypass ssl certificate checking in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806709/how-to-bypass-ssl-certificate-checking-in-java)

[Android ignore self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136694/android-ignore-self-signed-certificate)