# Kotlin Retrofit ignore https certifcate

Tags: kotlin, https, retrofit, okhttp

Kotlin Retrofit ignore https certifcate.

I tried this [Android ignore self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136694/android-ignore-self-signed-certificate) and converted to Kotlin. Its not working.

How can i ignore https (SSL) certificate.

My OkHttp is

````
import com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineCallAdapterFactory
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

object OwnRetrofitClient {

    private val authInterceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
        val newUrl = chain.request().url
            .newBuilder()
            .build()

        val newRequest = chain.request()
            .newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + AppPreferences.token)
            .url(newUrl)
            .build()

        chain.proceed(newRequest)
    }

    private val client =
        OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
            .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

    private fun retrofit(baseUrl: String = "https:some.com/api") =
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .build()

    fun apiService(): ApiService {
        return retrofit().create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The example you refer to, uses java built-in `HttpsUrlConnection`. In okhttp, you need to add the `X509TrustManager`, the `HostnameVerifier` and the `SSLSocketFactory` to `OkHttpClient.Builder` (see https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/-builder/ssl-socket-factory/)