# Can't fix AsyncTask crash: PendingIntent or SSL connection or other causes?

Tags: android, eclipse, ssl, android-asynctask, android-pendingintent

I have an Android app developed by me a couple a years ago. It is still on Play Store and I keep it updated fixing minor bugs with Eclipse and the old Android Development Tools (I never used Android Studio).

My app on first start-up starts downloading data from the server and save it on internal db (I used an AyncTask and here is the source code: https://pastebin.com/cKqXNYxm). All go well on most phones.

But on some phones the download fails and then the user can't use the app.
I get one of these phones and I attached it to LogCat to see what happen. Here is the log:

```
04-04 21:07:50.238: I/CastMediaRouteProvider(2082): in onDiscoveryRequestChanged: request=DiscoveryRequest{ selector=MediaRouteSelector{ controlCategories=[android.media.intent.category.LIVE_VIDEO, android.media.intent.category.REMOTE_PLAYBACK, com.google.android.gms.cast.CATEGORY_CAST/08FF1091, com.google.android.gms.cast.CATEGORY_CAST/4574A331] }, activeScan=false, isValid=true }
04-04 21:07:50.251: W/CastMediaRouteProvider(2082): Not a Cast compatible category: android.media.intent.category.LIVE_VIDEO
04-04 21:07:50.251: I/CastMediaRouteProvider(2082): Logging initial network connection state.
04-04 21:07:50.347: I/CastMediaRouteProvider(2082): Network connectivity changed
04-04 21:07:50.372: I/DeviceScanner(2082): [MDNS] Filter criteria: 08FF1091,CC1AD845,4574A331
04-04 21:07:50.372: I/DeviceScanner(2082): [MDNS] updateScannerState: No filter criteria was added.
04-04 21:07:50.372: I/DeviceScanner(2082): [MDNS] updateScannerState: No filter criteria was removed.
04-04 21:07:50.479: W/MdnsClient_Cast(2082): #acquireLock. Multicast lock not held. Acquiring. Subtypes:"4574A331,CC1AD845,08FF1091"
04-04 21:07:50.501: I/DeviceScanner(2082): [CastNearby] Filter criteria: 08FF1091,CC1AD845,4574A331
04-04 21:07:50.501: I/DeviceScanner(2082): [CastNearby] updateScannerState: No filter criteria was added.
04-04 21:07:50.501: I/DeviceScanner(2082): [CastNearby] updateScannerState: No filter criteria was removed.
04-04 21:08:08.860: W/IcingInternalCorpora(2082): getNumBytesRead when not calculated.
04-04 21:08:09.020: I/Icing(2082): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
04-04 21:08:09.063: I/Icing(2082): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
04-04 21:08:09.085: I/Icing(2082): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
04-04 21:08:09.100: I/Icing(2082): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
04-04 21:08:09.135: W/IcingInternalCorpora(2082): getNumBytesRead when not calculated.
04-04 21:08:09.265: I/art(1879): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 49907(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 18(288KB) LOS objects, 11% free, 22MB/26MB, paused 7.887ms total 67.577ms
04-04 21:08:10.048: I/Icing(2082): Indexing 26F5DFBF7CB0FE13B1ED2D2D8BA3F397144A57D1 from com.google.android.gms
04-04 21:08:10.078: W/Icing(2082): CLD2 bad utf8
04-04 21:08:10.114: I/Icing(2082): Indexing done 26F5DFBF7CB0FE13B1ED2D2D8BA3F397144A57D1
04-04 21:08:10.546: I/WearableService(1879): Wear is not allowed to run on this device. Not starting Wear service.
04-04 21:08:10.547: D/WearableService(1879): callingUid 10020, callindPid: 1879
04-04 21:08:23.830: I/CastMediaRouteProvider(2082): in onDiscoveryRequestChanged: request=null
04-04 21:08:23.840: W/MdnsClient_Cast(2082): Multicast lock held. Releasing. Subtypes:"4574A331,CC1AD845,08FF1091"
04-04 21:08:23.872: W/MdnsClient(2082): unicast receiver thread is already dead.
04-04 21:09:06.643: W/IcingInternalCorpora(2082): getNumBytesRead when not calculated.
04-04 21:09:06.814: I/Icing(2082): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
04-04 21:09:06.848: I/Icing(2082): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
04-04 21:09:06.881: I/Icing(2082): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
04-04 21:09:06.898: I/Icing(2082): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
04-04 21:09:06.958: W/IcingInternalCorpora(2082): getNumBytesRead when not calculated.
04-04 21:09:07.841: I/Icing(2082): Indexing 26F5DFBF7CB0FE13B1ED2D2D8BA3F397144A57D1 from com.google.android.gms
04-04 21:09:07.864: W/Icing(2082): CLD2 bad utf8
04-04 21:09:07.876: I/Icing(2082): Indexing done 26F5DFBF7CB0FE13B1ED2D2D8BA3F397144A57D1
04-04 21:09:43.012: W/GCoreFlp(1879): No location to return for getLastLocation()
04-04 21:09:51.519: W/IcingInternalCorpora(2082): getNumBytesRead when not calculated.
04-04 21:09:51.629: I/Icing(2082): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
04-04 21:09:51.674: I/Icing(2082): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
04-04 21:09:51.712: I/Icing(2082): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
04-04 21:09:51.767: I/Icing(2082): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
04-04 21:09:51.826: W/IcingInternalCorpora(2082): getNumBytesRead when not calculated.
04-04 21:09:52.662: I/Icing(2082): Indexing 26F5DFBF7CB0FE13B1ED2D2D8BA3F397144A57D1 from com.google.android.gms
04-04 21:09:52.682: W/Icing(2082): CLD2 bad utf8
04-04 21:09:52.699: I/Icing(2082): Indexing done 26F5DFBF7CB0FE13B1ED2D2D8BA3F397144A57D1
04-04 21:11:36.806: D/BluetoothAdapter(1879): 341170672: getState() :  mService = null. Returning STATE_OFF
04-04 21:13:50.296: V/NativeCrypto(1879): Read error: ssl=0xb84d38c0: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
04-04 21:13:50.315: V/NativeCrypto(1879): SSL shutdown failed: ssl=0xb84d38c0: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
04-04 21:13:50.333: W/GCM(1879): Lowering wifi heartbeat interval 1 notch to 230000, good=0 bad=2
04-04 21:18:17.073: D/BluetoothAdapter(1879): 341170672: getState() :  mService = null. Returning STATE_OFF
04-04 21:18:20.076: D/BluetoothAdapter(1879): 341170672: getState() :  mService = null. Returning STATE_OFF
04-04 21:18:20.528: I/Authzen(2082): [DeviceStateSyncManager] Device state fast sync is disabled
04-04 21:18:20.581: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:18:20.582: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:18:20.582: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:18:20.582: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:18:20.582: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:18:20.583: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:18:20.583: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:18:20.583: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:18:20.583: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:18:20.586: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:27:48.016: D/BluetoothAdapter(1879): 341170672: getState() :  mService = null. Returning STATE_OFF
04-04 21:29:01.013: D/BluetoothAdapter(1879): 341170672: getState() :  mService = null. Returning STATE_OFF
04-04 21:29:03.196: I/Authzen(2082): [DeviceStateSyncManager] Device state fast sync is disabled
04-04 21:29:03.233: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:29:03.233: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:29:03.233: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:29:03.234: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:29:03.234: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:29:03.234: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:29:03.235: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:29:03.235: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:29:03.235: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:29:03.236: I/DeviceCache(2082): Unable to convert the the network interface's MAC Address to string. MAC address cannot be null.
04-04 21:29:04.014: D/BluetoothAdapter(1879): 341170672: getState() :  mService = null. Returning STATE_OFF
04-04 21:29:10.297: W/GeofencerStateMachine(1879): Ignoring removeGeofence because network location is disabled.
04-04 21:29:11.075: E/WorkSourceUtil(2082): Could not find package: it.myapp.app
04-04 21:29:11.076: I/Icing(2082): doRemovePackageData it.myapp.app
04-04 21:29:11.133: I/LocationSettingsChecker(2082): Removing dialog suppression flag for package it.myapp.app
04-04 21:29:11.138: D/Wear_Controller(2082): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=it.myapp.app
04-04 21:29:11.295: E/NetworkScheduler.SR(1879): Invalid parameter app
04-04 21:29:11.296: E/NetworkScheduler.SR(1879): Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
04-04 21:29:11.461: W/IcingInternalCorpora(2082): getNumBytesRead when not calculated.
04-04 21:29:11.467: I/Icing(2082): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
04-04 21:29:11.475: I/Icing(2082): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
04-04 21:29:12.207: I/WearableService(1879): Wear is not allowed to run on this device. Not starting Wear service.
04-04 21:29:12.207: D/WearableService(1879): callingUid 10020, callindPid: 1879
04-04 21:29:12.482: I/Icing(2082): Indexing 11154CFA753891357620E30C887251401ECA34E6 from com.google.android.gms
04-04 21:29:12.517: I/Icing(2082): Indexing done 11154CFA753891357620E30C887251401ECA34E6
04-04 21:29:18.135: W/PlatformStatsUtil(2082): Could not retrieve Usage & Diagnostics setting. Giving up.
04-04 21:29:22.585: E/NetworkScheduler.SR(1879): Invalid parameter app
04-04 21:29:22.585: E/NetworkScheduler.SR(1879): Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
04-04 21:29:22.605: I/iu.Environment(2082): update battery state; isPlugged? true*
04-04 21:29:22.660: I/iu.FingerprintManager(2082): Start processing all media
04-04 21:29:22.870: I/iu.FingerprintManager(2082): Start processing media store URI: content://media/external/images/media
04-04 21:29:22.980: I/iu.UploadsManager(2082): num queued entries: 0
04-04 21:29:23.041: I/iu.UploadsManager(2082): num updated entries: 0
04-04 21:29:23.086: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(2082): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
04-04 21:29:23.091: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(2082): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db.18' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
04-04 21:29:23.094: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(2082): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
04-04 21:29:23.107: I/iu.SyncManager(2082): NEXT; no task
04-04 21:29:23.171: W/PlatformStatsUtil(2082): Could not retrieve Usage & Diagnostics setting. Giving up.
04-04 21:29:23.208: I/iu.FingerprintManager(2082): Start processing media store URI: content://media/external/video/media
04-04 21:29:23.214: I/iu.FingerprintManager(2082): Start processing media store URI: content://media/phoneStorage/images/media
04-04 21:29:23.216: I/iu.FingerprintManager(2082): Start processing media store URI: content://media/phoneStorage/video/media
04-04 21:29:23.237: I/iu.FingerprintManager(2082): Finished generating fingerprints; 0,577 seconds
04-04 21:29:23.238: I/iu.FingerprintManager(2082):   numSeen=1872 numGenerated=3 numDeleted=11 numFailed=0
04-04 21:29:33.041: W/PlatformStatsUtil(2082): Could not retrieve Usage & Diagnostics setting. Giving up.
04-04 21:29:35.099: D/Wear_Controller(2082): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=it.myapp.app
04-04 21:29:35.251: I/WearableService(1879): Wear is not allowed to run on this device. Not starting Wear service.
04-04 21:29:35.254: D/WearableService(1879): callingUid 10020, callindPid: 1879
04-04 21:29:35.279: I/Icing(2082): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
04-04 21:29:35.295: I/Icing(2082): Usage reports 0 indexed 0 rejected 0 imm upload false
04-04 21:29:35.320: W/IcingInternalCorpora(2082): getNumBytesRead when not calculated.
04-04 21:29:36.306: I/Icing(2082): Indexing 11154CFA753891357620E30C887251401ECA34E6 from com.google.android.gms
04-04 21:29:36.402: I/Icing(2082): Indexing done 11154CFA753891357620E30C887251401ECA34E6
04-04 21:29:40.870: W/PlatformStatsUtil(2082): Could not retrieve Usage & Diagnostics setting. Giving up.
```

I think the problem could be these messages:

```
04-04 21:29:11.295: E/NetworkScheduler.SR(1879): Invalid parameter app
04-04 21:29:11.296: E/NetworkScheduler.SR(1879): Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
```

...or maybe could be something related to SSL connection:

```
04-04 21:13:50.296: V/NativeCrypto(1879): Read error: ssl=0xb84d38c0: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
04-04 21:13:50.315: V/NativeCrypto(1879): SSL shutdown failed: ssl=0xb84d38c0: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
```

I can't figure out what could be the problem. I tried several devices and here is the result:

It works on the following phones:

- Huawei: 6.0
- Samsung A5: 6.0.1
- One Plus 2: 6.0.1
- Asus Zenphone: 6.1
- One Plus: 3 7.0
- HTC One: 7.0

It doens't work on following phones (it crashes during AsynTask execution):

- Samsung S3 Neo 4.4.2
- Asus 5.0.2
- Samsung S2 5.1.1
- Samsung Neo 5.1.1

Another thing that maybe is good to know for troubleshooting is that about 2 months ago I enabled an SSL certificate on my hosting, where the app get the data from.

I have already searched for similar questions about this problem, but none helped me.
Since in most phones the app works with no problem, I can't figure why on old version of Android it crashes with that LogCat. Any idea?

Comment: Are you using HttpsURLConnection?

Comment: As you can see in the Pastebin I have attached, I use `DefaultHttpClient`. How can I switch to `HttpsURLConnection`? Anyway why does it work on most phones?

Comment: I had a similar problem getting connection reset by peer in some phones with HttpsURLConnection due to used protocol. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649389/how-to-disable-sslv3-in-android-for-httpsurlconnection

Comment: Anyway, `apache.http` libs are deprecated so you should definitely update your connection framework. I'm pretty sure you will find an easy way to implement `HttpsUrlConnection` after research, it's simple, or other type of service lib.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will search to find a way to implement `HttpsUrlConnection`. Anyway what should I see at the link you posted?

Comment: That there is a bug in Androids < 4.4 with HttpsURLConnection when you are doing the SSL Certificate. The post with 20 up votes explains it and provides the full code to correct it

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you so much.

Comment: You say the app crashes, but in your logcat there is no crash. You need to find out where your app is crashing and add some logging. Then you can solve your problem. Updating your HTTP connection obviously isn't the problem, since your app works on newr phones but not older phones. Before ripping your app apart you should identify what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean "crash", I mean that I get an error that I throw when no data has been download from the server by the AsyncTask.

Comment: You need to add more logging to your `AsyncTask` so that you can determine why it isn't downloading any data. If you get an Exception thrown, all you do is call `printStackTrace()`. You should be calling `Log.e()` so it will show up in the logcat including the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of AsynTask error is the use of `DefaultHttpClient` with SSL connections. Android has deprecated the Apache module, that includes DefaultHttpClient, since API level 22.
I solved my problem replacing some code in `doInBackground` method.

Before:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    int timeout = 10;
    int i, count = 0;

    BasicHttpParams basicParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(basicParams, timeout * 1000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(basicParams, timeout * 1000 );
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(basicParams);

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urls[i]);
        request.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);

                count++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        publishProgress(count * 100 / urls.length);
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

After:

```
public static final int CONNECTON_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS = 60000;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    int i, count = 0;
    String urlsString = "";

    for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        try {
            urlsString += executeGetHttpRequest(urls[i]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }                   
        count++;

        publishProgress(count * 100 / urls.length);
    }
    return urlsString;
}

public static String executeGetHttpRequest(final String path) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    String result = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(path);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTON_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(CONNECTON_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
        result = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static String readStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        total.append(line);
    }
    if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
    }
    return total.toString();
}
```

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294699/2516399).

The above code is about a GET request. I also solved problems with AsyncTask in case of POST request thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13486223/2516399).