# HurlStack for Volley and one selfsigned certificate

Tags: android, ssl, android-volley

The old problem: Self signed certificates in Android. One way to solve this is the often suggested AlowAllTrustmanager. I tried it, it did not work. Then I found, at Google, this mthod: [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html)

I obtained the certificate, followed the description and can now open a HttpURLConnection to the server with the self signed certificate. So far, so good.

But I dont want to use HttpURLConnection directly, but want to use Volley insted.

So this is my question: How can I combine Volley with the method from Google? How can I make Volley create such a special HttpURLConnection any time it needs one? A friend suggested writing my own HurlStack and handingit to Volley, but I dont know hw to write one.

Any help or ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Pls read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673568/does-android-volley-support-ssl/32674422#32674422

Comment: @BNK the issue is that you have to have the certificate already in your project. What if you don't have this certificate?

Comment: @portfoliobuilder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051482/how-can-i-set-signalr-in-android-studio-to-ignore-ssl-issues-for-delvelopement/32051885#32051885